# How to find minimal polynomial and explicit matrix for the following conditions?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am given a matrix $A \in M(6\times6, \mathbb{R})$ such that $AA^T=A^TA$ (normal) and $P_A(t)=t^6-3t^2+2=(t-1)^2(t+1)^2(t^2+2)$, and the task is to find minimal polynomial and matrix itself.

As I saw, when calculating minimal polynomial it is usual to find characteristic polynomial and then reduce powers of factors and see what happens in this case to the matrix, but now I am not given a matrix, so I suppose here comes normality of matrix in play, but I can't see how.

I would appreciate any kind of help, thanks in advance.

Comment: What's $P_A(t)$?

Comment: Characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Since $A$ is normal, over $\mathbb{C}$, it is diagonalizable, and all eigenvectors to different eigenvalues are orthogonal. In other words, there is a unitary $U$ such that $U^\ast AU$ is diagonal.

Comment: @DanielFischer Why don't you answer more? I see you posting so many comments that are perfectly good answers.

Comment: Good question, @GitGud. In part, because I hate the feeling when an answer saying essentially the same is posted while I am (slowly) typing my answer. With a comment, on the one hand, it's not so frustrating when that happens, and on the other, it happens less because comments are shorter.

Comment: @DanielFischer You can post a hint as an answer and improve later if you want to.

Comment: Use the [characterisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Characterisation) that says that a matrix is diagonalizable if, and only if, its minimal polynomial consists only of linear factors. All of the eigenvalues must be roots of the minimal polynomial.

You also know that $A$ is diagonalizable. As for finding the matrix you can try to find a real $2\times 2$ matrix such that $U^*BU=\begin{pmatrix}i\sqrt 2 & 0\\ 0 & -i\sqrt 2 \end{pmatrix}$, for some $U$ and you know that $U$'s columns are eigenvectors and $B$ is $A$'s block that will yield the nonreal eigenvalues.

Comment: @haemhweg The motivation for finding such $B$# is the fact that any normal matrix is unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is normal. So, it is orthogonally similar to its *[real Jordan form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices)* over $\mathbb{R}$. That is,
$$
A=Q\pmatrix{I_2\\ &-I_2\\ &&0&-\sqrt{2}\\ &&\sqrt{2}&0}Q^T
$$
for some real orthogonal $Q$ and the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(t-1)(t+1)(t^2+2)$.